# Using foreach() in a string using android

Tags: android, foreach

I am trying to use `foreach()` in Android:

I have a String `String str1= "1E25E453e5dU543K24L"` and I am trying to put "-" after every four digits like a product key.

I tried in C# it works for me.

```
foreach (char cMAC in str1){
        i++;
        if (i == 4 || i == 8 || i == 12 || i == 16)
             txtRegisterKey.Text += cMAC.ToString() + " - ";
        else
             txtRegisterKey.Text += cMAC.ToString();
}
```

I want to do same thing in android, Do I get any Ideas. Thank You in advance

Comment: A `for` loop works fine for this. Is there any specific reason you want to use a `foreach`?

Comment: `String` does not implement `Iterable<Character>`, nor `Iterable<char>`(latter is not even valid in Java), so you cannot do that.

Comment: I have to try this in android but didn't work. For for loop it asks me to change into Char array[] were I have both integer and Character in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep the same approach and use a `StringBuilder` to build your new string:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String s = "1E25E453e5dU543K24L";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
    sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    if (i % 4 == 3) {
        sb.append('-');
    }
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this while the user enters the key, you can use a `TextWatcher`.

```
private final TextWatcher dashWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           if (i == 4 || i == 8 || i == 12 || i == 16){
             s.append("-");
           }
        }
    };
```

Add it to your EditText like this:

```
 youreditText.addTextChangedListener(dashWatcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elegant solution using while. Foreach is too complicated for this problem.

```
    // Add - symbol after every forth later.
    StringBuilder bkp16 = new StringBuilder("1E25E453e5dU543K24L");
    int idx = 4;

    while (bkp16.length() > idx){
        bkp16.insert(idx, "-");
        idx = idx + 1 + 4;
    }

    return bkp16.toString();
```